# does limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2+ixy}{1-z\bar z}$ exist?

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to determine whether the next limit exists:
$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2+ixy}{1-z\bar z}$

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2+ixy}{1-z\bar z}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2+ixy}{1-x^2-y^2}$

So

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2+ixy}{1-z\bar z}=\frac{0}{1-y^2}=0 ?$

Is this correct?, But what if $y$ takes $1$ or$-1$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like 0 to me!

Comment: If $y=\pm1$ then it reduces to $0/\pm\infty$. What must that be?

Comment: If $y=±1$ then it reduces to $0/0$

Comment: It is not clear in you question whether you consider this limit for some fixed $y,$ or you let $y$ vary.

Answer (score 2):

The case $y^2\neq 1$ seems correct the way it is. For $y=\pm 1$ the limit becomes
$$\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^2+ixy}{1-x^2-y^2} = \lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^2\pm ix}{-x^2} = \lim _{x\rightarrow 0}-(1\pm i/x)$$
which diverges.

Hope that helps :)